# What does "class :" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I've never seen it before. I thought it was a typo for "::sample", but when I saw it actually compiles I was very confused. Can anyone help me find out please? I don't think it's a `goto` label.

```
void f() {
  class: sample {
    // there were some members declared here
  } x;
}
```

Comment: Looks like an anonymous class (which inherits from sample) instance x. Never saw this before. Maybe it's C++0x?

Comment: just guessing: could this be unnamed class deriving from `sample`?

Comment: It's not a `goto` label? Correct, `goto` the top of the `class`!

Comment: I didn't even notice that this was you. Pfft.

Comment: @Johannes Check out this [code review proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") if you haven't already. The site can definitely benefit from your C++ prowess.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It is an unnamed class, and the colon means it inherits privately from `sample`. See it like

```
class Foo : private sample
{
    // ...
};

Foo x;
```

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. It seems you are right, there is a class "sample" in scope and the class members access the base class. Now I see.

Comment: @Johannes: this is quite limited an approach, since the unnamed class cannot have non default constructors or destructor, nor can it be used as a template (since it is a local class). I'd be curious about what the use of this construct is. The only use case I know for local classes is the "type erasure idiom" (ie. returning a `sample*`, but `sample` is an inaccessible base class here).

Comment: @Alexandre it didn't happen in real code. It was one of my playground files.

Comment: It's not an un-named class instance; it's an un-named class.

Answer (score 21):

I think that is defining **an unnamed class** deriving from `sample`. And `x` is a variable of that unnamed class.

```
struct sample{ int i;};

sample f() 
{
  struct : sample 
  {
    // there were some members declared here
  } x;
  x.i = 10;
  return x;
}
int main() 
{
        sample s = f();
        cout << s.i << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Sample code at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/6Mj8x

PS: I changed `class` to `struct` for accessibility reason!

Answer (score 2):

That's an unnamed class.

You can use them e.g. to substitute for local functions in pre-C++11:

```
int main() {
    struct {
        int operator() (int i) const {                 
            return 42;
        }
    } nice;

    nice(0xbeef);
}
```

The colon followed by  `sample` simply means *derive from `sample` using default inheritance*. (for structs: public, for classes: private)